# How would I change the value in an object using .find?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find a specific modlog then change the reasoning of it.

This is how I currently have it:

```
data.modLogs.find((c) => c.case === parseInt(args[1])).reason = newReason
data.save()
```

But it doesn't seem to work, my code gives me the 'ok' and says it's saved but no changes have been made. Is there another way I should be doing this?

Comment: Try to use updateOne instead.. when it comes to nested object and lists it is less effective that way...

Comment: I'll try it, thanks